# Shift between connection strings

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, connection-string

I'm new to asp.net MVC.
I'm currently re-writing an application which was originally developed using asp vb.net 1.1  from asp c#.net 4.5 & mvc.

I already designed the login screen using the mvc simplemembership provider. But the problem is this application uses multiple databases for different office locations. i.e. login users will be provided with dropdown list box (site) to select the location apart from the user name & password. based on the location selected, application should look users details in different databases.

[image]

Following is how the multiple connection strings appears in the existing application.

```
        <appSettings>
            <add key="DBConnection_bk" value="Server=server1;UID=sa;PWD=*****;pooling=false;connect timeout=800;database=bangkong;"/>
            <add key="DBConnection_dxb" value="Server=server1;UID=sa;PWD=*****;pooling=false;connect timeout=800;database=dubai;"/>        
            <add key="DBConnection_hk" value="Server=server1;UID=sa;PWD=*****;pooling=false;connect timeout=800;database=Hongkong;"/>
            <add key="DBConnection_syd" value="Server=server1;UID=sa;PWD=*****;pooling=false;connect timeout=800;database=sydney;"/>
            <add key="DBConnection_sha" value="Server=server1;UID=sa;PWD=*****;pooling=false;connect timeout=800;database=shanghai;"/>         
                <add key="crServerName" value="server1" />
                <add key="crLogin" value="sa" />
                <add key="crPassword" value="*****" />  
                <add key="crDBConnection_bk" value="bangkong" />
                <add key="crDBConnection_dxb" value="dubai" />
                <add key="crDBConnection_hk" value="hongkong" />
                <add key="crDBConnection_syd" value="sydney" />
                <add key="crDBConnection_sha" value="shanghai" />
        </appSettings>
```

My question is can I archive the same functionality with MVC 4? i.e. based on the drop down list box (site) value selected, can I select the connection string internally?

I'm also open for suggestion. if above is not the right way, what is the best way to archive this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IMHO before even thinking about switching from a cs to another you should seriously reconsider having things like user names and passwords stored as plain text in your config file and login to a database as System Administrator from a Web application (or any application for that matter).

Comment: It will be a concern towards end of the project but I have bigger concerns to get this up and running now.

Answer (score 1):

You should build your connection string dynamically from both code and config.

You may store possible target servers and databases in your config file, as well as settings like connection timeout and pooling, but each as individual config values rather than duplicating them over and over in connection strings.

Use list of servers and databases to build up your site combobox and depending on both the user input and config settings, build the connection string.

```
public bool TryLogin(out connectionString)
{
    // set connectionString using input controls and config settings, as you see fit

    using (var cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            cn.Open();
            cn.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            // connection attempt failed
            return false;
        }

        // connection attempt succeeded, connection string proven to be valid
        return true;
    }
}
```

I would also recommend that you take a look on [how to make your own configuration elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) in a web.config file. This would help enforce your settings typing and make their usage in code a lot clearer.

Doing that, your config file could end up having something like this:

```
<dbSettings timeout="800" pooling="false">
    <possibleDbs>
        <db server="server1" database="bangkong"/>
        <db server="server1" database="shangai"/>
        <!-- etc -->
    </possibleDbs>
</dbSettings>
```

As you can see this is a lot cleaner and safer. Depending on your requirements you could probably do even better.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your answer is bit irrelevant. why we cannot simply encrypt the connection string on the config file? However I'm not too worried about it at this stage. All I'm worried about is linking user inputs to connection strings. eg. how do you link user module and site details? how do I modify auth controller to validate site inputs? etc...I'm sorry but still I don't see a way out with your answer.

Comment: I meant can I pass site input to the dbcontext class? if yes, would you mind giving me some code snippets?

Comment: @ecasper Your question never mentionned encryption. And even if it did, I would have still proposed this answer because as you mentioned, you were open to suggestions. :)

Comment: @ecasper as for linking user inputs to connection strings, it is unclear to me what challenges you are facing here. You know how to build a string, right? Then simply append the different parameters and values of your connection in a string object which you'll then be able to pass to your `DbContext` class. If you look at the doc you'll see that `DbContext` accepts a connection string as constructor parameter.

Comment: @ecasper also the link I've provided about custom configuration sections will help you building a config front class to access settings. The class will likely expose a collection of valid servers and databases which your auth controller can use to validate user input. I hope you'll understand that I can't show you actual code here as it'd be too much of a guess without knowing your structure (and frankly a bit long for SO standards). Still, this should give you more than enough to get you quite reasonably far down the road.